# scala selenium dsl page object

Tags: scala, selenium-webdriver

I am using the Selenium dsl and would like to use a Page object. Currently however it seems I have to define the page object inside the test class.  The reason I would want a page object is to share common features between tests so this seems a bit pointless...  Has anyone been using the page object model with Selenium DSL?  What is the idea behind defining the page object in the same class?  How come I get a compiler error if I define the page object outside of the test class.  Am I doing something wrong?

The compiler error I get is:

Expected MySpec.this.type#Page, actual: MyPage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the class outside of the test class like this:

```
class TwitterPage {
  val url = "http://twitter.com"
}
```

Then, use it inside the test by *mixing in* the Page trait:

```
val page = new TwitterPage with Page
go to page
title should be ("Welcome to Twitter")
```

This compiled and worked just fine for me.